# Pandas plot series after sort_values produce weird chart

Tags: python, pandas, plot

Having the following DF, plotting `A` series produce the expected chart:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[9,4,2,5,4,6,1,1,9,8,7,4,3,1,6,4]})
df.A.plot()
```

[image]

But after sorting the values:

```
df.sort_values(by='A',inplace=True)
df.A.plot()
```

The result looks wrong,  what am I missing?
[image]

Comment: The index needs to be reset before plotting: `df.reset_index(drop=True).A.plot()` and it should work

Answer (score 1):

You need to call reset_index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[9,4,2,5,4,6,1,1,9,8,7,4,3,1,6,4]})
df = df.sort_values(by='A').reset_index(drop=True)

df['A'].plot()
```